# Globally generated sheaf is globally generated by fewer sections away from finitely many points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, k3-surfaces

Assume $S$ is a smooth projective surface and $E$ is a nontrivial torsion free sheaf of rank $r$ on $S$ that comes with a surjective morphism $\mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus t}\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$ for some $t>r$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is it always possible (depending on $S$) to find a free subsheaf $\mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus r+1}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus t}$ such that the composition $\mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus r+1}\rightarrow E$ is surjective, except at maybe finitely many points in $S$?

This result is stated for a $K3$-surface (without proof) in Mukai's "Duality of polarized K3 surfaces" on page 320. So maybe this is something very obvious? But I was unable to prove this for myself. If it is obvious I am happy just to see a refrence in the literature. Otherwise how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true; in fact, this is a version of the Bertini theorem.

To prove consider the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(r+1,t)$ with the tautological subbundle $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{O}^{\oplus t}$. Further, consider the product $S \times \mathrm{Gr}(r+1,t)$ and the composition
$$
\mathcal{O} \boxtimes \mathcal{U} \hookrightarrow 
(\mathcal{O} \boxtimes \mathcal{O})^{\oplus t} \twoheadrightarrow
E \boxtimes \mathcal{O}.
$$
Let $D \subset S \times \mathrm{Gr}(r+1,t)$ be its degeneration locus (i.e., the locus where the composition is not surjective). The fiber $D_s$ of the projection $D \to S$ over a point $s \in S$ parameterizes all $(r+1)$-dimensional subspaces in the $t$-dimensional space $\Bbbk^t$ that intersect the $(t - r)$-dimensional kernel $\mathrm{Ker}(\Bbbk^t \twoheadrightarrow E_s)$ in a subspace of dimension $\ge 2$. Therefore, 
$$
\dim(D_s) = 2(t - r - 2) + (r-1)(t-r-1) = (r+1)(t-r-1) - 2.
$$
Thus, $D_s$ has codimension 2 in the fiber of $S \times \mathrm{Gr}(r+1,t)$ over $s \in S$, hence $D$ has codimension 2 in the product. Now it follows that for a general point $U \subset \mathrm{Gr}(r,t+1)$ the fiber $D_U$ of $D$ over $U$ has codimension 2. It remains to note that $D_U$ is precisely the locus of points of $S$, where the composition
$$
U \otimes \mathcal{O} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}^{\oplus t} \twoheadrightarrow E
$$
is not surjective.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can follow your argument, if we assume $E$ is locally free, then the fibers $E_s$ are all of dimension $r$. But in my case $E$ is just torsion free, which leads to 2 questions: for some (finitely many) points $s\in S$ the fiber could be of dimension $> r$ which means the kernel of $k^t \rightarrow E_s$ is of dimension $<(t-r)$. Does your argument still apply? A second question: I know how the degeneracy locus works for two locally free sheaves. Does everything work the same for torsion free sheaves?

Comment: Just replace $S$ by the maximal open subset $S_0 \subset S$ over which $E$ is locally free. The above argument shows that over $S_0$ a general subspace $U$ generates $E$ away from a finite number of points. Since $S \setminus S_0$ is finite the same subspace works over $S$.

Comment: Of course, this was obvious, I should have seen this. When trying to write this up for myself today, I found one problem. When you compute the dimension of $D_s$ the first summand should come from the Grassmannian of $2$-planes in the $(t-r)$-dimensional kernel. But I cannot figure out where the second summand comes from. I first thought that this comes from the Grassmannian, but then it would have to be $(r+1)(t-r-1)$ instead of $(r-1)(t-r-1)$. So I must have misread the first time. Where does the second summand come from, especially the $(r-1)$?

Comment: This is the dimension of the subvariety of $Gr(r+1,t)$ parameterizing subspaces containing a given 2-dimensional subspace; this subvariety is isomorphic to $Gr(r-1,t-2)$.